# Hiding the auxilary files as part of the compilation script under OS X

Tags: texshop, mac, auxiliary-files

I'm aware that there is a lot of discussion about what to do with the pile of auxiliary files that LateX creates when it compiles. What I want to do is pretty specific.

The simplest thing I've found to do is to just set the BSD style "hidden" flag for all of the files in the directory. Anything more complicated (like creating a directory for them) usually clashes when I'm sharing a workspace.  OS X doesn't have a great way of doing this automatically, and I really only want it for directories I'm actually using for LaTeX. Consequently, I wrote an Applescript that just does this:

```
do shell script "cd " & (quoted form of POSIX path of currentDir) & "; chflags hidden *.nav *.out *.log *.gz *.snm *.toc *.aux *.bbl *.blg"
```

Then I invoke it whenever I feel the need.

I always figured it would be simpler to just build the flag change into the compile script, but my attempts at doing so haven't gotten very far. I'm using TexShop BTW.

Is there a way to do this, or is this just a dumb idea.